# Limiting sequence of exponential random variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, martingales, law-of-large-numbers

> Let $\eta_k$ be i.i.d. random variables having an exponential distribution,
>   $$F_\lambda(x) = P(\eta_k \leq x) = 1-e^{-\lambda x}$$ for $x \geq 0$. Consider a sequence $\xi_k = F_{\lambda}(\eta_k)$. Define 
>   $$X_n = \left(\prod_{k=1}^{n} \xi_k\right)^{1/n}.$$
>   Find $\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n$. Is $X_n$ a martingale, submartingale, or super martingale ?

My attempts/remarks:

$lim_{n \to \infty} X_n = lim_{n \to \infty} (\prod_{k=1}^{n} \xi_k)^{1/n} =lim_{n \to \infty} (\prod_{k=1}^{n} 1-e^{-\lambda \eta_k})^{1/n}$

How can I continue from here? I also have problems with the definition of $\xi_k := F_{\lambda}(\eta_k)$, since $F_{\lambda}(\eta_k) = P(\eta_k \leq \eta_k) = P(0 \leq 0)=1$. Huh? Could the author have meant something else? What am I missing here?

**My work from some hints in the comments:**
We can easily compute that $f_{\xi_k}(x)=1$ for $x \in (0,1)$. Then, we compute:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \log{X_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log{\xi_k}}{n}=E[log(\xi_k)] = \int_{0}^{1}1*log(\tau) d\tau = -1.$$
It follows by monotone convergence theorem that 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} e^{\log{X_n}} = e^{-1}$$

Note that for every $n\ge2$,
$$E[X_n|F_{n-1}] = E[(\prod_{k=1}^{n} \xi_k)^{1/n}|F_{n-1}]= E[(\xi_n)^{1/n}{(\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \xi_k)^{1/(n-1)}}^{(n-1)/n}|F_{n-1}] = (X_{n-1})^{(n-1)/n}E[(\xi_n)^{1/n}] = (X_{n-1})^{(n-1)/n} \int_{0}^{1}(\tau)^{1/n} d \tau = (X_{n-1})^{(n-1)/n} \dfrac{n}{n+1} =??$$
I am stuck here.

Comment: First of all, $F_{\lambda}(\eta_k) \ne P(\eta_k \leq \eta_k)$, rather, *by the definition in your post*, $F_{\lambda}(\eta_k) = 1-e^{-\lambda\eta_k}$. Second, try to compute the distribution of $\xi_k$ and of $\log\xi_k$.

Comment: @Did I computed that $\xi_k$ is equal in distribution to $1-(1-x)^{\lambda - x}$, and $\log{\xi_k}$ is equal in distribution to $1-(1-e^x)^{\lambda - x}$.

Comment: Do you mean that the PDF of $\xi_k$ would be this? Then you ought to redo your computations. Presenting them here in details might help.

Comment: @Did Those distributions are CDF's. Do you still believe they are wrong?

Comment: Yes they are. $ $

Comment: @Did New results are: $f_{\xi_k}(x)= 1$, and $f_{log(\xi_k)}(x) = -e^{-x}$

Comment: The second PDF should be nonnegative but ok, now what can you say about $\log X_k=\frac1k\sum\limits_{i=1}^k\log\xi_i$ when $k\to\infty$?

Comment: @Did As $k \to \infty$, we have (by law of large numbers) that $\dfrac{1}{k} \sum_{i=1}^{k} \log{\xi_i}$ converges to the expected value of $log(\xi_i)$.

Comment: That is right. And thus?

Comment: Ah, we are one step back: no, $F_{\xi}$ is not what you compute (I thought you said that $f_\xi(x)=1$ for every $x$ in $(0,1)$, and now what is this $F_\xi$ you are proposing?).

Comment: @Did Please see my work in my post.

Comment: $$F_\xi(x) = P(\xi \leqslant x) = P(1-e^{-\lambda\eta} \leqslant x) = P(\eta\leqslant -\lambda^{-1}\log(1-x))=\ldots$$

Comment: @Did I updated my work above.

Comment: Right, so you have the almost sure limit. Now to the other properties...

Comment: @Did I showed the sequence is a supermartingale. Please see my work above.

Comment: Why do you state that $$\left(X_{n-1}\right)^{(n-1)/n} \dfrac{n}{n+1} < X_{n-1}\ ?$$

Comment: @Did I was unsure of this step. My "sketchy" reasoning was: Since $\xi_k$ only takes values in $]0,1[$, we have that $X_n$ only takes values in $]0,1[$. Then I tried a bunch of examples, and concluded that the inequality is true. I am unsure if this is correct, and unsure how to prove this inequality rigorously (if it is true).

Comment: Of course it is not true. Note that $$x^{(n-1)/n}n/(n+1)<x\iff n/(n+1)<x^{1/n}\iff x>(n/(n+1))^n$$ hence every $x$ in $(0,1)$ small enough disproves it.

Comment: @Did On the other hand, if $$x^{(n-1)/n} n/ (n+1) > x$$ then, $$n/(n+1) > x^{1/n} \iff x < (n/(n+1))^n$$ So the assumptions that $$x^{(n-1)/n} n/ (n+1) > x$$ and $$x^{(n-1)/n} n/ (n+1) < x$$ are both not true.

Comment: @Did Is it possible that this sequence is neither a submartingale, supermartingale nor a martingale?

Comment: Indeed it is...

Comment: @Did I'm finding it difficult to visualize a random sequence which converges to a constant, which is not a martingale, but also neither converges from above, nor below. It seems contradictory to me. I tried plotting a few simulations of this convergence. The sequence will sometimes behave like a supermartingale, and sometimes behave like a submartingale (in the same simulation). Although I know its true, I don't see how a sequence can converge without one of the three properties holding.

Comment: Can u please elaborate little bit@Kerry